Alignment for an AI based on Biblical Hermeneutics, has to seek a baseline. How, with the restrictions imposed on asking questions, can alignment work
This is an amazing issue to attempt to tackle. We as human beings don't align very well. Basic terms such as 'truth', 'fact', 'meaning' and 'reality' are all subject to an individuals experience to life and it's various happenings. All of which can offend, may cause debate, or conflict in understandings and cognitive dissonance. Avoiding any of these creates bias, lack understanding and perspective. I am not a scholar, I was an IT professional whose very first readings were about AI and it's challenges. Agreeing to disagree and expound upon it is necessary to achieve a base alignment from which all else can be obtained. How about, "Christ is King", or "Creation", or "Historical Recorded Verified Events", or "God, not man, inspired all scripture." and "Referring to oldest historically verifiable sources." IDK, this is all subjective, However, CAN IT BE ACHIEVED?

Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for joining our group.  Please remember to take the tour (link bottom left) to better understand how this site is different.  Valid questions here need a specific Bible passage to analyze.

The Spirit: 1 Cor 2:10-13 "But God hath revealed them unto us by his Spirit: for the Spirit searcheth all things, yea, the deep things of God. 11 For what man knoweth the things of a man, save the spirit of man which is in him? even so the things of God knoweth no man, but the Spirit of God. 12 Now we have received, not the spirit of the world, but the spirit which is of God; that we might know the things that are freely given to us of God. 13 Which things also we speak, not in the words which man's wisdom teacheth, but which the Holy Ghost teacheth; comparing spiritual things with spiritual."

Welcome to the Biblical Hermeneutics SE. We are glad you are here. Please take a moment to take the site tour and check out educating new users and the FAQs. We're passionate about high quality answers. Also consider going through the Help Center's sections on asking and answering questions.

To make alignment work when interpreting the Bible through a lens like Biblical Hermeneutics, the first step is to get everyone on the same page about a few basic truths (Nicene Creed for example). Things like the fact that Jesus is the central figure, the Bible is divinely inspired, and its main message is about salvation through Christ. These are the core beliefs that all Christians can agree on, because they define Christianity. Once you’ve got those down, you can start from a place of unity, even if you disagree on the finer details.
Next, it’s important to stick to facts and history. The Bible wasn’t written in 2024, so understanding it requires knowing what it meant when it was first written. The AI could help by focusing on the oldest, most reliable texts and pulling from solid historical research, like archaeology and scholarly work, to make sure the interpretations are grounded in the way the original audience would’ve understood them. That way, you're not just guessing about what a verse means today based on modern ideas, but looking at what it would’ve meant in its time.
The method of interpretation should also stay consistent. This means focusing on the literal meaning of the text unless there’s a clear reason to see it symbolically or metaphorically. And any interpretation should fit within the bigger theological story—things like who Jesus is and the plan for salvation. If the interpretation doesn’t line up with these bigger truths, then it’s probably off track.

"the first step is to get everyone on the same page about a few basic truths" — If we could get everyone on the same page, there wouldn't be thousands of different denominations calling themselves "Christian". ¶ "Nicene Creed for example" ­— which of course excludes all those denominations that don't believe it 100%.

Most denominations disagree on the more advanced truths, not necessarily on the basic ones. There has to be a line drawn somewhere for being a Christian, or otherwise the word loses the meaning. It is generally thought that the Nicene Creed is just that line, below which denominations are not Christian.
